# Is there any way to read a csv file from specific line to end of the file by using php?

Tags: php

So my csv file format would be like this

```
Site：
Site ID：
Owner:
Interval:
Location:
Last Record:
---Data From User File---：
Date, Content
2019-01-10-12:15, 1
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.5
2019-01-10-12:15, 0.8
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.4
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.9
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.4
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.6
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.7
2019-01-10-12:15, 1.1
```

And I need do start to read csv file from line 10 (2019-01-10-12:15, 1) to end of the file by using php. I have check most of methods online and it did not help me to solve the problem, my code is provided below.

and it turned out to be reading the previous 8 lines(which is opposite of what I want).

```
<?php
    $index = 8;
    $i = 1;
    $file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($file);
    while (! feof($file)) {
        if ($index >= $i) {
            print_r($data = fgetcsv($file));
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($file);

?>
```

Need to read from line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$skip_lines = 8;
$i = 0;
$file = fopen('/path/to.csv', 'r');
while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if($i++ >= $skip_lines) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: This is pretty much copied from the manual.  So if you down-vote, kindly leave an explainer.  Thanks.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Norrius thanks for the comment, the OPs code seems to be a resource hog/infinite loop?  And TBH I can't determine why as I'm not familiar with feof.  Glancing the man page for fgetcsv, gives example use, similar to here.  On top of that the variable naming should be obvious enough.

Comment: Wait I thought I clicked this one as the answer for the question....I am sorry I just switched answer to yours...and Idk why for some reason I can not upvote your answer...

Comment: @HeYifan I have no idea how voting works.  Just pick the answer that best answers your question.  If a better one comes along by all means select.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several solutions to process your data.

As your other lines does not start with a number, what I would do is check first character of new line is numeric or not (get first character by using PHP's `substr()` function and then check that variable it with `is_numeric()` function). If you get a numeric value, that is your first useful line.